# Can anybody help me in replacing '>' with '>\n' inside string in java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Can anybody help me in replacing `>` with `>\n` inside string in java?

For example:

```
String str = "abc>";
str = str.replace(">",">\n");
```

Comment: hmmm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44686185/java-string-replaceall-not-working

Comment: Do you mean a newline character, or do you mean a backslash and an n?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3788176)

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to replace `>` with `>` followed by a newline character, then

```
str = str.replace(">",">\n");
```

will do it.

If instead you want to replace `>` with `>\n` (literally `>`, followed by `\`, followed by `n`), then you need to escape the backslash in the replacement string by preceding it with another backslash:

```
str = str.replace(">",">\\n");
```